# Index rebuild/reorganize fragmentation percentage mean the internal (inside the page) or external (amongst pages)fragmentation?

Tags: sql-server, index, index-maintenance

Fragmentation of 5% - reorganize

Fragmentation of 30% - rebuild

Index rebuild/reorganize fragmentation percentage mean the internal (inside the page) or external (amongst pages)fragmentation?

Answer (score 1):

Those numbers refer to external fragmentation.

Note that with modern disk-subsystems you likely won't gain anything, or very little, by defragmenting your indexes. I have blogged about it, including some measurements, here: https://sqlblog.karaszi.com/index-fragmentation-revisited/

Comment: So what does 30% external fragmentation exactly mean? Is it that 30% of the pages are not in physical order?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The value is calculated based on how many time it has to go backwards in the database file to get to next page, instead of forward.